# Unity Container Resolved Instances Post Processing

Tags: unity-container

I want to implement something similar to this: http://www.kjetilk.com/2011/10/auto-wiring-eventaggregator.html. 
But instead of using InterceptingCatalog, I want to do the wiring after the Resolve method of the Unity Container is called and the class implementing IHandle is resolved. Is there any support for post processing resolved instances right after they are resolved in Unity?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [TecX project on codeplex](http://tecx.codeplex.com). The source contain exactly what you are looking for in *TecX.Event.Unity*

Comment: I also found this to be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539811/is-there-a-good-way-to-use-events-with-unity