# unity container - intercept instance creation

Tags: c#, unity-container

Is it possible to intercept instance creation with unity IoC container? I would like to use it for registering all instances implementing specific interface.

Example - when new instance is created by unity container, this code should be performed:

```
IRegistrable registrable = newInstance as IRegistrable;
if (registrable!=null) { someService.Register(registrable) }
```

So all instances implementing IRegistrable will be registered automaticaly by the container.

Thank for your advice!

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539811/is-there-a-good-way-to-use-events-with-unity/8540833#8540833). The solution should work for your problem as well.

Comment: I would like to.. but I don't have enough reputation yet for vote (12 is minimum:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [interceptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647107.aspx).

Comment: I know there are Interceptors in unity, but I couldn't figure out how to use them in my scenario. I think they are useful only for interception when calling methods.

Comment: Unity.AutoRegistration is  your friend,